# opencv kmeans return wrong cluster centers from picture

Tags: c++, opencv, k-means

I'm trying to get the centers of the clusters from a depth frame, but can't the correct coordinates. I'm following a example given on stack overflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36696009/9615473), but my matrix is 512*424 of type CV_16SC1 (ushort, one channel).
No matter what i do, i get the wrong or none center's return (on the left top corner instead of middle center). Can anyone explains to me how to do it?
Here is a sample of the original and output: [images](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Agwll3M-mvkLgTxFxtsA6yZwD8ob)

```
//my code so far:
FILE *infile= NULL; 
fopen_s(&infile, p1ficheiro, "rb"); //if... blá blá

unsigned short *buffer = new unsigned short[512*424];
fread(buffer, 512 * 424, sizeof(unsigned short), infile)

//entry matrix
Mat frame(424,512,CV_16SC1,buffer);

int dimension = 8;

//working Mat
Mat temp;
frame.copyTo(temp);
temp.convertTo(temp, CV_32FC1);
temp.reshape(dimension , (512 * 424) / dimension );

//going to kmeans...
Mat labels, centers;
kmeans(temp, dimension , labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER | CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000,0.001), 10, KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS, centers);

//finding centers
for (int j = 0; j < centers.rows; ++j)
{
std::cout << centers.row(j) << std::endl;
circle(temp, Point(centers.at<float>(j, 0), centers.at<float>(j, 1)), 30, Scalar::all(255), 2);
}

//just so it's more clear to the eye
frame.convertTo(frame, CV_16SC1, 8);
imshow("IN",frame);
imshow("OUT",temp);
waitkey(0);

//... close and free everything...
```

Comment: [MCVE] (complete means it compiles as is -- currently it certainly won't), sample input that reproduces the problem, and some elaboration on what you consider "correct coordinates" and how the actual result differs from your expectation.

Comment: How about an example image and the bad results you get on it?

Comment: I don´t have the points, so... linked to the cloud. Tks for caring.